# Почему возникает ошибка «ModuleNotFoundError» при запуске .py файла через cmd, ошибка в импорте?

Tags: python

Возникает ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...' . Из ошибки понял, что он не видит папку AATC, хоть и главный запускающий файл находится именно там.
Хочу понять, что приводить к данной ошибке и как от неё избавиться.
В моем проекте используется файл python, который вызывает другой .py файл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как он может увидеть папку AATC, если он находится внутри её? Попробуйте `from main ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы запускаете этот файл внутри папки AATC, вам следует написать

```
from main import trafData
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло для вызова через CMD, однако через запуск в IDE выдает ошибку с путями. Можно ли создать какое нибудь условие, которое понимало, когда система запрашивает с IDE и CMD?

Comment: 1) Нажми правую кнопку мыши на папке AATC
2) Ищи вкладку  "Mark Directory as" 
3) И выбери из выпадающего меню "souces root"

Comment: Большое спасибо